# DynamoDB, what's better: multiple small queries or one big query?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have the following dataset

```
Post Table

| UserID | title     |
-----------------------
| userA  | Article 1 |
| userA  | Article 2 |
| userB  | Article 3 |
| userC  | Article 4 |
| userB  | Article 5 |
```

I'd like to **get all the articles from userA and userB**.
In reality, I can have 50 userIDs in input and a thousand of posts in the output.

What is the best way to perform a such query:

- A GSI on the UserID and a query for each (50 queries with a few rows returned)
- A Scan with a filter on the userID using a "IN" filter ?
- Any other solution ?

Using MySQL, I knew  it was better to do one big query than many smalls. But is this true with DynamoDB ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using DynamoDB, you need to stop thinking about SQL databases. The paradigm is completely different.

To answer your question, it is best to use one query because small queries will always round up your Read Capacity even if you don't use it all.

Avoid Scan as much as possible, it is the most expensive one as the filtering happens **AFTER** all the documents have been read.

### Deep dive in DynamoDB

In your case, I see a clear access pattern where your `Primary Key` is a combination of `UserID` (your `hashKey`) and `title` (your `rangeKey`).

However, that would make your table very strict, meaning that your `hashKey` is always a `UserId` and your `rangeKey` a `title`. So instead of naming your keys as `UserId` and `title` just use generic names, such as `pk` and `sk`, these being just strings. This way you can do very powerful queries (the most efficient way to get info from your table) like `pk=userA and sk BEGINS_WITH Article`. But this assumes that all your article start with the word `Article` which I don't think it would be the case.

Going a bit further, and to enable you to have a single table app, you can prefix your different entities at the time of saving them. For example, you could prefix all your `UserId` with `USER#` and all your article `title` with `ART#`, so your table would look like (note the new names of the columns):

```
Post Table

| pk          | sk            |
------------------------------
| USER#userA  | ART#Article 1 |
| USER#userA  | ART#Article 2 |
| USER#userB  | ART#Article 3 |
| USER#userC  | ART#Article 4 |
| USER#userB  | ART#Article 5 |
```

With this setup, you can do now `pk=USER#userA and sk BEGINS_WITH ART#` to give you in **JUST ONE** query, all the articles for `userA`

With this prefixing approach, nothing stops you from having a heteregenous single table (the real power of DynamoDB is about to be unleashed). For example:

```
My heteregenous Table

| pk            | sk            |
--------------------------------
| USER#userA    | ART#Article 1 |
| USER#userA    | ART#Article 2 |
| USER#userB    | ART#Article 3 |
| USER#userC    | ART#Article 4 |
| USER#userB    | ART#Article 5 |
| ART#Article 5 | COM#Comment 1 |
| ART#Article 5 | COM#Comment 2 | 
| ART#Article 6 | COM#Comment 1 |
| ART#Article 6 | COM#Comment 2 |
```

What if you want all comments for a given article? Easy `pk=ART#Article 5 and sk BEGINS_WITH COM#`

Finally, you can use a technique called **Inverted Index** to create a GSI where you just switch your `pk` for your `sk` and your `sk` for your `pk` to give you even more potential queries. This is clearly explained in the first of these masterpieces, which I recommend you to watch in this order:

1. [AWS re:Invent 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIQVJqiSUkE&ab_channel=AWSEvents)
2. [AWS re:Invent 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k&ab_channel=AmazonWebServices)